# How do I show relationships between type variables

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, dependent-type, higher-kinded-types

For the types `Door` and `Hallway`:

```
 data DoorState :: Type where
   Opened :: DoorState
   Closed :: DoorState
   Locked :: DoorState
   deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)

 data Door :: DoorState -> Type where
   Door :: {material :: String} -> Door s
   deriving (Show)

 data Hallway :: [DoorState] -> Type where
   Origin :: Hallway '[]
   Section :: Door ds -> Hallway dsl -> Hallway (ds : dsl)
```

This definition of `appendHallway` works:

```
 appendHallway :: forall (ds :: DoorState) (dsl :: [DoorState]). Door ds -> Hallway dsl -> Hallway (ds : dsl)
 appendHallway d rest = Section d rest
```

However this definition for `appendHallway` where the relationship between `ds` and `dsl` is being explicitly indicated in the `forall` section does not work:

```
 appendHallway :: forall t (ds :: t) (dsl :: [t]). (t ~ DoorState) => Door ds -> Hallway dsl -> Hallway (ds : dsl)
 appendHallway d rest = Section d rest
```

The error that is returned is as follows:

```
 error:
     • Expected kind ‘DoorState’, but ‘ds’ has kind ‘t’
     • In the first argument of ‘Door’, namely ‘ds’
       In the type signature:
         appendHallway :: forall t (ds :: t) (dsl :: [t]).
                          (t ~ DoorState) => Door ds -> Hallway dsl -> Hallway (ds : dsl)
     |
 351 | appendHallway :: forall t (ds :: t) (dsl :: [t]). (t ~ DoorState) => Door ds -> Hallway dsl -> Hallway (ds : dsl)
     |                                                                           ^^
```

The example above may be a little contrived, but there might be situations where indicating relationships between higher kinded type variables would be helpful or even necessary.  Is this error a limitation of the current version of GHC or is the above nonsensical even in a future version of GHC?  Is there another way to express the relationship between `ds` and `dsl` that would be accepted by GHC?

Comment: How is `DoorState` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you have written is indeed nonsense. The constraints on the LHS of a `=>` exist only on the value-level, in the same way things on the LHS of a `->` exist only on the value-level. More specifically (though this is a faint memory), an instance of `a ~ b` "contains" within it a primitive type of kind `a ~# b` (in the same way a `data Showable = forall s. Show s => Showable s` holds a type of kind `Type`). You need the `a ~# b` to actually get anything done, but you'd need to unpack the `a ~ b` to get it. You cannot talk about the `a ~ b`, a value-level argument, in a type, though, in the same way you cannot talk about the `DoorState` in `DoorState -> Door _can'tTalkAboutTheDoorState`.

What you can do is this. Define

```
type family Cast (x :: (a :: Type)) :: (b :: Type) where
   Cast x = x
-- this seems strange, but realize the equation is actually
-- Cast @a @a (x :: a) = (x :: a)
-- Cast-ing some type from one kind to another only goes through
-- when they're actually the same kind
-- can make a, b, or both explicit instead of implicit
```

Then

```
appendHallway :: forall t (ds :: t) (dsl :: [t]).
                 (t ~ DoorState) =>
                 Door (Cast ds) ->
                 Hallway (Cast dsl) ->
                 Hallway (Cast ds : Cast dsl)
appendHallway d rest = Section d rest
```

Whenever `t ~ DoorState` is known, the type family applications `Cast @t @DoorState ds` and `Cast @[t] @[DoorState] dsl` reduce to `ds` and `dsl` respectively.

Comment: "The constraints on a type are value-level" - things that live in a type signature are by definition not "value-level", right? So what do you mean?

Comment: @jberryman In `a ~ b => ()`, the `a ~ b` is value-level in the same way as the `DoorState` in `DoorState -> ()`.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up going with this: https://gist.github.com/binq/89999480859905af982b45c8a9df2ed4

Answer (score 2):

Haskell has separate namespaces for computations, types, and kinds. When you write

```
forall (ds :: t). ...
```

the variable `t` is the kind-level variable, but when you write

```
t ~ DoorState => ...
```

the variable `t` is the type-level variable `t`, a completely unrelated variable. Indeed, all type equalities are at the type-level only; as far as I know there is no way to express kind equalities as constraints at all in current GHC Haskell.

Comment: What? No. Kinds are types. Values have types. Types also have types. Note that `Type :: Type`. If a type is the type of a type, then we sometimes call it a "kind" in the simple cases where the distinction is convenient. `~` constraints are value level. "Inside" a `~`, I believe, lies a type level coercion, but you can't unpack a value-level argument to a function inside its type to get to it.